# In which format the contacts are stored in android?

Tags: android, android-contacts

I want to know in which format the contact details are stored in android mobile or emulator.If any body knows the answer please help me.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The contacts are stored in a SQLite3 database file so the file format is ".db"

The development tool [Android Debug Bridge](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/guide/developing/tools/adb.html) (ADB) can be used to extract the file from an **EMULATOR**

ADB can also extract the file from a phone but it must be rooted first AND the ADB drivers must be installed on your machine as well

(Rooting is **NOT** for beginners though)

The contacts.db file is stored in the protected system memory, the file path is:

data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts.db

Comment: If you place that contacts file on SD, you can replace that /data/ file on the system with the root mode in Ghost Commander, force close the contacts app and run it again, you will have your contacts back :)

Comment: when we backing up of contacts whit witch format they saves?

Answer (score 4):

You can access contact information programmatically using [ContactsContract](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html) and [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) (in Android 2.0); there's an example on how to do so in the SDK, called [Contact Manager](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ContactManager/index.html).

Comment: You can also modify contacts automatically in plain text, but not directly. In contacts menu on Android 2.3.4 I had "backup" and "import" buttons; I "backed up" contacts to know what format are they (It was [vCard format 2.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard#Example_vCard_files)), then wrote shell script to generate these contacts from names & phone numbers I had, copied this file to phone and finally "imported" it.